# an if Statement inside an if Statement?

Tags: python, variables

```
FarmGround=input("Do you want to pat the animal? ") #this is the input
if FarmGround==("Yes") or FarmGround==("yes"):  #this is if
    print("You patted the animal")  #print statement if you patted the animal it will go onto the next if statement
if print=("You patted the animal"):
elif FarmGround==("No") or FarmGround==("no"): #this is elif
    print("You didn't patt the animal and it is triggered")
```

[undescribed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaqYl.png)

Comment: sorry it not in python language i have autism and i am bad at stackflow if anyone can teach me how to put it in programming language also would hlep :^)

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: i want to put an if statement inside an if statement.

Comment: In what language?

Comment: @mememan If you hover beside the existing `variables` tag, you will see an "Edit tags" link appear. Click that, and add `python`.

Comment: @mememan Your code generally makes sense except for this line: `if print=("You patted the animal"):` What is that supposed to mean? I think you can just delete it.

Comment: Like if they patted the animal then i want them to be asked another if statement but only if they patted the animal.

Comment: can you please help me i am severely autistic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite clear. What I understand is you want to ask another question if animal is patted.

```
FarmGround=input("Do you want to pat the animal? ") #this is the input

if FarmGround=="Yes" or FarmGround=="yes":  #this is if
    print("You patted the animal") 

    holy_field = input("Did you clear the field?") 
    if holy_field.lower() == "yes":
         print("Do something else. Don't look at me.") 
    else: 
         print("When are you going to do it ?")          
elif FarmGround== "No" or FarmGround== "no": #this is elif
    print("You didn't patt the animal and it is triggered")
```

Comment: i want this but i dont want an input

Answer (score 2):

You can indent additional statements, including `if` statements inside your existing `if` block, just like you're indented the first `print` statement. It's not clear from your question what exactly you want to do, so I'll fill in some pseudo-code (which you can replace with whatever you actually want):

```
FarmGround=input("Do you want to pat the animal? ")
if FarmGround==("Yes") or FarmGround==("yes"):
    print("You patted the animal")
    some_other_answer = input("Some other question?")  # here's more code inside the first if
    if some_other_answer == "Foo":   # it can include another if statement, if you want it to
        print("Foo!")
elif FarmGround==("No") or FarmGround==("no"):
    print("You didn't patt the animal and it is triggered")
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation matters in python. To nest an if statement in another if statement, just indent it below the first with 4 spaces.

```
If ( var1 == 1 ):
    If ( var2 == 2 ):
        print "Both statements are true."
```